# Can 42 1x2x4 cuboids be packed into a 7x7x7 cube?

Tags: mathematics, geometry, three-dimensional, packing

Can 42 1x2x4 cuboids be packed into a 7x7x7 cube without cutting any of them? Assume that all cuboids have their axes parallel to the axes of the big cube. I tried using https://www.jaapsch.net/puzzles/polysolver.htm but it didn't find any answer quickly enough. I also tried various coloring techniques to prove impossibility, but none seemed to work.

If it is impossible, is there any elegant proof?

41 cuboids is possible (image taken directly from Polyform Puzzle Solver):  [image]

Comment: Similar: https://puzzling.stackexchange.com/questions/62780/how-many-2-times-2-times-1-blocks-can-you-put-in-a-3-times-3-times-3-cub?rq=1

Comment: The analysis of the linked puzzle works on this one too, at least to some extent, so the 7 empty spots in a 42-piece solution are very restricted in their arrangement. The coordinates of each space is either all even or all odd, and no two spaces have any coordinate in common.

Answer (score 8, accepted):

Via integer linear programming, the maximum is

> $41$.

For each of the $1008$ possible boxes $b$, let $C_b \subset [7] \times [7] \times [7]$ be the set of cells covered by $b$, and let binary decision variable $x_b$ indicate whether box $b$ is used.  The problem is to maximize $\sum_b x_b$ subject to linear "packing" constraints
$$\sum_{b: (i,j,k) \in C_b} x_b \le 1
\quad \text{for all $(i,j,k)\in [7]\times[7]\times[7]$}$$

The linear programming relaxation has maximum objective value

> $41 + 9/11$,

achieved by the following fractional solution, where each row shows $C_b$ and $x_b$:

```
{(1,1,1),(1,1,2),(1,1,3),(1,1,4),(1,2,1),(1,2,2),(1,2,3),(1,2,4)} 1117/4576
{(1,1,4),(1,1,5),(1,1,6),(1,1,7),(1,2,4),(1,2,5),(1,2,6),(1,2,7)} 827/4576
{(1,2,1),(1,2,2),(1,2,3),(1,2,4),(1,3,1),(1,3,2),(1,3,3),(1,3,4)} 1265/4576
{(1,4,2),(1,4,3),(1,4,4),(1,4,5),(1,5,2),(1,5,3),(1,5,4),(1,5,5)} 388/4576
{(1,5,1),(1,5,2),(1,5,3),(1,5,4),(1,6,1),(1,6,2),(1,6,3),(1,6,4)} 365/4576
{(1,5,4),(1,5,5),(1,5,6),(1,5,7),(1,6,4),(1,6,5),(1,6,6),(1,6,7)} 1020/4576
{(1,6,1),(1,6,2),(1,6,3),(1,6,4),(1,7,1),(1,7,2),(1,7,3),(1,7,4)} 86/4576
{(1,6,4),(1,6,5),(1,6,6),(1,6,7),(1,7,4),(1,7,5),(1,7,6),(1,7,7)} 1430/4576
{(2,2,1),(2,2,2),(2,2,3),(2,2,4),(2,3,1),(2,3,2),(2,3,3),(2,3,4)} 586/4576
{(2,2,4),(2,2,5),(2,2,6),(2,2,7),(2,3,4),(2,3,5),(2,3,6),(2,3,7)} 807/4576
{(2,5,1),(2,5,2),(2,5,3),(2,5,4),(2,6,1),(2,6,2),(2,6,3),(2,6,4)} 1130/4576
{(3,1,3),(3,1,4),(3,1,5),(3,1,6),(3,2,3),(3,2,4),(3,2,5),(3,2,6)} 266/4576
{(3,2,2),(3,2,3),(3,2,4),(3,2,5),(3,3,2),(3,3,3),(3,3,4),(3,3,5)} 278/4576
{(3,4,2),(3,4,3),(3,4,4),(3,4,5),(3,5,2),(3,5,3),(3,5,4),(3,5,5)} 171/4576
{(3,4,3),(3,4,4),(3,4,5),(3,4,6),(3,5,3),(3,5,4),(3,5,5),(3,5,6)} 829/4576
{(3,6,1),(3,6,2),(3,6,3),(3,6,4),(3,7,1),(3,7,2),(3,7,3),(3,7,4)} 790/4576
{(3,6,2),(3,6,3),(3,6,4),(3,6,5),(3,7,2),(3,7,3),(3,7,4),(3,7,5)} 217/4576
{(3,6,3),(3,6,4),(3,6,5),(3,6,6),(3,7,3),(3,7,4),(3,7,5),(3,7,6)} 615/4576
{(4,3,1),(4,3,2),(4,3,3),(4,3,4),(4,4,1),(4,4,2),(4,4,3),(4,4,4)} 506/4576
{(4,3,4),(4,3,5),(4,3,6),(4,3,7),(4,4,4),(4,4,5),(4,4,6),(4,4,7)} 278/4576
{(4,6,1),(4,6,2),(4,6,3),(4,6,4),(4,7,1),(4,7,2),(4,7,3),(4,7,4)} 890/4576
{(4,6,4),(4,6,5),(4,6,6),(4,6,7),(4,7,4),(4,7,5),(4,7,6),(4,7,7)} 275/4576
{(5,1,2),(5,1,3),(5,1,4),(5,1,5),(5,2,2),(5,2,3),(5,2,4),(5,2,5)} 658/4576
{(5,1,3),(5,1,4),(5,1,5),(5,1,6),(5,2,3),(5,2,4),(5,2,5),(5,2,6)} 910/4576
{(5,3,2),(5,3,3),(5,3,4),(5,3,5),(5,4,2),(5,4,3),(5,4,4),(5,4,5)} 368/4576
{(5,3,3),(5,3,4),(5,3,5),(5,3,6),(5,4,3),(5,4,4),(5,4,5),(5,4,6)} 1443/4576
{(5,4,2),(5,4,3),(5,4,4),(5,4,5),(5,5,2),(5,5,3),(5,5,4),(5,5,5)} 300/4576
{(5,5,3),(5,5,4),(5,5,5),(5,5,6),(5,6,3),(5,6,4),(5,6,5),(5,6,6)} 319/4576
{(5,6,1),(5,6,2),(5,6,3),(5,6,4),(5,7,1),(5,7,2),(5,7,3),(5,7,4)} 569/4576
{(5,6,2),(5,6,3),(5,6,4),(5,6,5),(5,7,2),(5,7,3),(5,7,4),(5,7,5)} 722/4576
{(5,6,4),(5,6,5),(5,6,6),(5,6,7),(5,7,4),(5,7,5),(5,7,6),(5,7,7)} 868/4576
{(6,2,1),(6,2,2),(6,2,3),(6,2,4),(6,3,1),(6,3,2),(6,3,3),(6,3,4)} 905/4576
{(6,2,3),(6,2,4),(6,2,5),(6,2,6),(6,3,3),(6,3,4),(6,3,5),(6,3,6)} 110/4576
{(6,2,4),(6,2,5),(6,2,6),(6,2,7),(6,3,4),(6,3,5),(6,3,6),(6,3,7)} 1177/4576
{(6,5,4),(6,5,5),(6,5,6),(6,5,7),(6,6,4),(6,6,5),(6,6,6),(6,6,7)} 912/4576
{(7,1,1),(7,1,2),(7,1,3),(7,1,4),(7,2,1),(7,2,2),(7,2,3),(7,2,4)} 212/4576
{(7,1,4),(7,1,5),(7,1,6),(7,1,7),(7,2,4),(7,2,5),(7,2,6),(7,2,7)} 684/4576
{(7,2,1),(7,2,2),(7,2,3),(7,2,4),(7,3,1),(7,3,2),(7,3,3),(7,3,4)} 119/4576
{(7,2,4),(7,2,5),(7,2,6),(7,2,7),(7,3,4),(7,3,5),(7,3,6),(7,3,7)} 2135/4576
{(7,3,3),(7,3,4),(7,3,5),(7,3,6),(7,4,3),(7,4,4),(7,4,5),(7,4,6)} 266/4576
{(7,5,1),(7,5,2),(7,5,3),(7,5,4),(7,6,1),(7,6,2),(7,6,3),(7,6,4)} 950/4576
{(7,5,4),(7,5,5),(7,5,6),(7,5,7),(7,6,4),(7,6,5),(7,6,6),(7,6,7)} 167/4576
{(7,6,1),(7,6,2),(7,6,3),(7,6,4),(7,7,1),(7,7,2),(7,7,3),(7,7,4)} 1504/4576
{(1,1,2),(1,1,3),(1,2,2),(1,2,3),(1,3,2),(1,3,3),(1,4,2),(1,4,3)} 446/4576
{(1,1,5),(1,1,6),(1,2,5),(1,2,6),(1,3,5),(1,3,6),(1,4,5),(1,4,6)} 1083/4576
{(1,1,6),(1,1,7),(1,2,6),(1,2,7),(1,3,6),(1,3,7),(1,4,6),(1,4,7)} 931/4576
{(1,2,1),(1,2,2),(1,3,1),(1,3,2),(1,4,1),(1,4,2),(1,5,1),(1,5,2)} 147/4576
{(1,2,4),(1,2,5),(1,3,4),(1,3,5),(1,4,4),(1,4,5),(1,5,4),(1,5,5)} 636/4576
{(1,3,3),(1,3,4),(1,4,3),(1,4,4),(1,5,3),(1,5,4),(1,6,3),(1,6,4)} 237/4576
{(1,3,6),(1,3,7),(1,4,6),(1,4,7),(1,5,6),(1,5,7),(1,6,6),(1,6,7)} 192/4576
{(1,4,1),(1,4,2),(1,5,1),(1,5,2),(1,6,1),(1,6,2),(1,7,1),(1,7,2)} 1369/4576
{(1,4,2),(1,4,3),(1,5,2),(1,5,3),(1,6,2),(1,6,3),(1,7,2),(1,7,3)} 995/4576
{(1,4,5),(1,4,6),(1,5,5),(1,5,6),(1,6,5),(1,6,6),(1,7,5),(1,7,6)} 430/4576
{(1,4,6),(1,4,7),(1,5,6),(1,5,7),(1,6,6),(1,6,7),(1,7,6),(1,7,7)} 993/4576
{(2,1,2),(2,1,3),(2,2,2),(2,2,3),(2,3,2),(2,3,3),(2,4,2),(2,4,3)} 740/4576
{(2,1,5),(2,1,6),(2,2,5),(2,2,6),(2,3,5),(2,3,6),(2,4,5),(2,4,6)} 401/4576
{(2,4,5),(2,4,6),(2,5,5),(2,5,6),(2,6,5),(2,6,6),(2,7,5),(2,7,6)} 1364/4576
{(3,1,1),(3,1,2),(3,2,1),(3,2,2),(3,3,1),(3,3,2),(3,4,1),(3,4,2)} 1384/4576
{(3,1,6),(3,1,7),(3,2,6),(3,2,7),(3,3,6),(3,3,7),(3,4,6),(3,4,7)} 553/4576
{(3,2,3),(3,2,4),(3,3,3),(3,3,4),(3,4,3),(3,4,4),(3,5,3),(3,5,4)} 962/4576
{(3,2,6),(3,2,7),(3,3,6),(3,3,7),(3,4,6),(3,4,7),(3,5,6),(3,5,7)} 560/4576
{(3,3,1),(3,3,2),(3,4,1),(3,4,2),(3,5,1),(3,5,2),(3,6,1),(3,6,2)} 451/4576
{(3,4,6),(3,4,7),(3,5,6),(3,5,7),(3,6,6),(3,6,7),(3,7,6),(3,7,7)} 941/4576
{(4,1,1),(4,1,2),(4,2,1),(4,2,2),(4,3,1),(4,3,2),(4,4,1),(4,4,2)} 2139/4576
{(4,1,6),(4,1,7),(4,2,6),(4,2,7),(4,3,6),(4,3,7),(4,4,6),(4,4,7)} 642/4576
{(4,4,3),(4,4,4),(4,5,3),(4,5,4),(4,6,3),(4,6,4),(4,7,3),(4,7,4)} 228/4576
{(4,4,6),(4,4,7),(4,5,6),(4,5,7),(4,6,6),(4,6,7),(4,7,6),(4,7,7)} 1892/4576
{(5,1,1),(5,1,2),(5,2,1),(5,2,2),(5,3,1),(5,3,2),(5,4,1),(5,4,2)} 679/4576
{(5,1,6),(5,1,7),(5,2,6),(5,2,7),(5,3,6),(5,3,7),(5,4,6),(5,4,7)} 1049/4576
{(5,2,1),(5,2,2),(5,3,1),(5,3,2),(5,4,1),(5,4,2),(5,5,1),(5,5,2)} 504/4576
{(5,2,4),(5,2,5),(5,3,4),(5,3,5),(5,4,4),(5,4,5),(5,5,4),(5,5,5)} 278/4576
{(5,2,6),(5,2,7),(5,3,6),(5,3,7),(5,4,6),(5,4,7),(5,5,6),(5,5,7)} 463/4576
{(5,3,1),(5,3,2),(5,4,1),(5,4,2),(5,5,1),(5,5,2),(5,6,1),(5,6,2)} 348/4576
{(5,3,3),(5,3,4),(5,4,3),(5,4,4),(5,5,3),(5,5,4),(5,6,3),(5,6,4)} 405/4576
{(6,1,2),(6,1,3),(6,2,2),(6,2,3),(6,3,2),(6,3,3),(6,4,2),(6,4,3)} 322/4576
{(6,1,5),(6,1,6),(6,2,5),(6,2,6),(6,3,5),(6,3,6),(6,4,5),(6,4,6)} 1135/4576
{(6,4,2),(6,4,3),(6,5,2),(6,5,3),(6,6,2),(6,6,3),(6,7,2),(6,7,3)} 1475/4576
{(7,1,1),(7,1,2),(7,2,1),(7,2,2),(7,3,1),(7,3,2),(7,4,1),(7,4,2)} 2275/4576
{(7,1,2),(7,1,3),(7,2,2),(7,2,3),(7,3,2),(7,3,3),(7,4,2),(7,4,3)} 1006/4576
{(7,1,5),(7,1,6),(7,2,5),(7,2,6),(7,3,5),(7,3,6),(7,4,5),(7,4,6)} 451/4576
{(7,2,1),(7,2,2),(7,3,1),(7,3,2),(7,4,1),(7,4,2),(7,5,1),(7,5,2)} 504/4576
{(7,3,4),(7,3,5),(7,4,4),(7,4,5),(7,5,4),(7,5,5),(7,6,4),(7,6,5)} 553/4576
{(7,4,1),(7,4,2),(7,5,1),(7,5,2),(7,6,1),(7,6,2),(7,7,1),(7,7,2)} 164/4576
{(7,4,2),(7,4,3),(7,5,2),(7,5,3),(7,6,2),(7,6,3),(7,7,2),(7,7,3)} 525/4576
{(7,4,5),(7,4,6),(7,5,5),(7,5,6),(7,6,5),(7,6,6),(7,7,5),(7,7,6)} 786/4576
{(7,4,6),(7,4,7),(7,5,6),(7,5,7),(7,6,6),(7,6,7),(7,7,6),(7,7,7)} 2044/4576
{(1,1,1),(1,1,2),(1,1,3),(1,1,4),(2,1,1),(2,1,2),(2,1,3),(2,1,4)} 586/4576
{(1,1,2),(1,1,3),(1,1,4),(1,1,5),(2,1,2),(2,1,3),(2,1,4),(2,1,5)} 285/4576
{(1,1,4),(1,1,5),(1,1,6),(1,1,7),(2,1,4),(2,1,5),(2,1,6),(2,1,7)} 1030/4576
{(1,3,1),(1,3,2),(1,3,3),(1,3,4),(2,3,1),(2,3,2),(2,3,3),(2,3,4)} 340/4576
{(1,3,2),(1,3,3),(1,3,4),(1,3,5),(2,3,2),(2,3,3),(2,3,4),(2,3,5)} 679/4576
{(1,3,3),(1,3,4),(1,3,5),(1,3,6),(2,3,3),(2,3,4),(2,3,5),(2,3,6)} 510/4576
{(1,3,4),(1,3,5),(1,3,6),(1,3,7),(2,3,4),(2,3,5),(2,3,6),(2,3,7)} 909/4576
{(1,4,1),(1,4,2),(1,4,3),(1,4,4),(2,4,1),(2,4,2),(2,4,3),(2,4,4)} 550/4576
{(1,4,4),(1,4,5),(1,4,6),(1,4,7),(2,4,4),(2,4,5),(2,4,6),(2,4,7)} 947/4576
{(1,5,2),(1,5,3),(1,5,4),(1,5,5),(2,5,2),(2,5,3),(2,5,4),(2,5,5)} 160/4576
{(1,5,4),(1,5,5),(1,5,6),(1,5,7),(2,5,4),(2,5,5),(2,5,6),(2,5,7)} 1430/4576
{(1,7,1),(1,7,2),(1,7,3),(1,7,4),(2,7,1),(2,7,2),(2,7,3),(2,7,4)} 1007/4576
{(1,7,3),(1,7,4),(1,7,5),(1,7,6),(2,7,3),(2,7,4),(2,7,5),(2,7,6)} 192/4576
{(1,7,4),(1,7,5),(1,7,6),(1,7,7),(2,7,4),(2,7,5),(2,7,6),(2,7,7)} 423/4576
{(2,1,1),(2,1,2),(2,1,3),(2,1,4),(3,1,1),(3,1,2),(3,1,3),(3,1,4)} 389/4576
{(2,1,4),(2,1,5),(2,1,6),(2,1,7),(3,1,4),(3,1,5),(3,1,6),(3,1,7)} 1325/4576
{(2,2,1),(2,2,2),(2,2,3),(2,2,4),(3,2,1),(3,2,2),(3,2,3),(3,2,4)} 781/4576
{(2,2,4),(2,2,5),(2,2,6),(2,2,7),(3,2,4),(3,2,5),(3,2,6),(3,2,7)} 762/4576
{(2,6,4),(2,6,5),(2,6,6),(2,6,7),(3,6,4),(3,6,5),(3,6,6),(3,6,7)} 1516/4576
{(2,7,1),(2,7,2),(2,7,3),(2,7,4),(3,7,1),(3,7,2),(3,7,3),(3,7,4)} 1020/4576
{(2,7,4),(2,7,5),(2,7,6),(2,7,7),(3,7,4),(3,7,5),(3,7,6),(3,7,7)} 496/4576
{(3,1,2),(3,1,3),(3,1,4),(3,1,5),(4,1,2),(4,1,3),(4,1,4),(4,1,5)} 227/4576
{(3,1,3),(3,1,4),(3,1,5),(3,1,6),(4,1,3),(4,1,4),(4,1,5),(4,1,6)} 612/4576
{(3,3,2),(3,3,3),(3,3,4),(3,3,5),(4,3,2),(4,3,3),(4,3,4),(4,3,5)} 232/4576
{(3,3,3),(3,3,4),(3,3,5),(3,3,6),(4,3,3),(4,3,4),(4,3,5),(4,3,6)} 1084/4576
{(4,5,2),(4,5,3),(4,5,4),(4,5,5),(5,5,2),(5,5,3),(5,5,4),(5,5,5)} 192/4576
{(4,5,3),(4,5,4),(4,5,5),(4,5,6),(5,5,3),(5,5,4),(5,5,5),(5,5,6)} 808/4576
{(4,7,2),(4,7,3),(4,7,4),(4,7,5),(5,7,2),(5,7,3),(5,7,4),(5,7,5)} 721/4576
{(4,7,3),(4,7,4),(4,7,5),(4,7,6),(5,7,3),(5,7,4),(5,7,5),(5,7,6)} 192/4576
{(5,1,1),(5,1,2),(5,1,3),(5,1,4),(6,1,1),(6,1,2),(6,1,3),(6,1,4)} 896/4576
{(5,2,4),(5,2,5),(5,2,6),(5,2,7),(6,2,4),(6,2,5),(6,2,6),(6,2,7)} 848/4576
{(5,3,2),(5,3,3),(5,3,4),(5,3,5),(6,3,2),(6,3,3),(6,3,4),(6,3,5)} 402/4576
{(5,6,1),(5,6,2),(5,6,3),(5,6,4),(6,6,1),(6,6,2),(6,6,3),(6,6,4)} 1504/4576
{(5,6,4),(5,6,5),(5,6,6),(5,6,7),(6,6,4),(6,6,5),(6,6,6),(6,6,7)} 189/4576
{(5,7,1),(5,7,2),(5,7,3),(5,7,4),(6,7,1),(6,7,2),(6,7,3),(6,7,4)} 718/4576
{(5,7,4),(5,7,5),(5,7,6),(5,7,7),(6,7,4),(6,7,5),(6,7,6),(6,7,7)} 786/4576
{(6,1,1),(6,1,2),(6,1,3),(6,1,4),(7,1,1),(7,1,2),(7,1,3),(7,1,4)} 1015/4576
{(6,1,4),(6,1,5),(6,1,6),(6,1,7),(7,1,4),(7,1,5),(7,1,6),(7,1,7)} 1239/4576
{(6,3,1),(6,3,2),(6,3,3),(6,3,4),(7,3,1),(7,3,2),(7,3,3),(7,3,4)} 672/4576
{(6,3,4),(6,3,5),(6,3,6),(6,3,7),(7,3,4),(7,3,5),(7,3,6),(7,3,7)} 831/4576
{(6,4,4),(6,4,5),(6,4,6),(6,4,7),(7,4,4),(7,4,5),(7,4,6),(7,4,7)} 1029/4576
{(6,5,2),(6,5,3),(6,5,4),(6,5,5),(7,5,2),(7,5,3),(7,5,4),(7,5,5)} 548/4576
{(6,5,3),(6,5,4),(6,5,5),(6,5,6),(7,5,3),(7,5,4),(7,5,5),(7,5,6)} 956/4576
{(6,7,1),(6,7,2),(6,7,3),(6,7,4),(7,7,1),(7,7,2),(7,7,3),(7,7,4)} 164/4576
{(6,7,2),(6,7,3),(6,7,4),(6,7,5),(7,7,2),(7,7,3),(7,7,4),(7,7,5)} 446/4576
{(6,7,4),(6,7,5),(6,7,6),(6,7,7),(7,7,4),(7,7,5),(7,7,6),(7,7,7)} 1060/4576
{(1,1,1),(1,2,1),(1,3,1),(1,4,1),(2,1,1),(2,2,1),(2,3,1),(2,4,1)} 1554/4576
{(1,1,7),(1,2,7),(1,3,7),(1,4,7),(2,1,7),(2,2,7),(2,3,7),(2,4,7)} 572/4576
{(1,2,3),(1,3,3),(1,4,3),(1,5,3),(2,2,3),(2,3,3),(2,4,3),(2,5,3)} 976/4576
{(1,3,1),(1,4,1),(1,5,1),(1,6,1),(2,3,1),(2,4,1),(2,5,1),(2,6,1)} 275/4576
{(1,3,5),(1,4,5),(1,5,5),(1,6,5),(2,3,5),(2,4,5),(2,5,5),(2,6,5)} 106/4576
{(1,4,3),(1,5,3),(1,6,3),(1,7,3),(2,4,3),(2,5,3),(2,6,3),(2,7,3)} 492/4576
{(1,4,7),(1,5,7),(1,6,7),(1,7,7),(2,4,7),(2,5,7),(2,6,7),(2,7,7)} 941/4576
{(2,1,1),(2,2,1),(2,3,1),(2,4,1),(3,1,1),(3,2,1),(3,3,1),(3,4,1)} 826/4576
{(2,1,2),(2,2,2),(2,3,2),(2,4,2),(3,1,2),(3,2,2),(3,3,2),(3,4,2)} 434/4576
{(2,1,6),(2,2,6),(2,3,6),(2,4,6),(3,1,6),(3,2,6),(3,3,6),(3,4,6)} 700/4576
{(2,1,7),(2,2,7),(2,3,7),(2,4,7),(3,1,7),(3,2,7),(3,3,7),(3,4,7)} 189/4576
{(2,2,2),(2,3,2),(2,4,2),(2,5,2),(3,2,2),(3,3,2),(3,4,2),(3,5,2)} 98/4576
{(2,4,1),(2,5,1),(2,6,1),(2,7,1),(3,4,1),(3,5,1),(3,6,1),(3,7,1)} 690/4576
{(2,4,2),(2,5,2),(2,6,2),(2,7,2),(3,4,2),(3,5,2),(3,6,2),(3,7,2)} 1357/4576
{(2,4,6),(2,5,6),(2,6,6),(2,7,6),(3,4,6),(3,5,6),(3,6,6),(3,7,6)} 993/4576
{(2,4,7),(2,5,7),(2,6,7),(2,7,7),(3,4,7),(3,5,7),(3,6,7),(3,7,7)} 1927/4576
{(3,1,4),(3,2,4),(3,3,4),(3,4,4),(4,1,4),(4,2,4),(4,3,4),(4,4,4)} 796/4576
{(3,2,3),(3,3,3),(3,4,3),(3,5,3),(4,2,3),(4,3,3),(4,4,3),(4,5,3)} 796/4576
{(3,2,5),(3,3,5),(3,4,5),(3,5,5),(4,2,5),(4,3,5),(4,4,5),(4,5,5)} 664/4576
{(3,3,5),(3,4,5),(3,5,5),(3,6,5),(4,3,5),(4,4,5),(4,5,5),(4,6,5)} 638/4576
{(4,1,4),(4,2,4),(4,3,4),(4,4,4),(5,1,4),(5,2,4),(5,3,4),(5,4,4)} 456/4576
{(4,2,3),(4,3,3),(4,4,3),(4,5,3),(5,2,3),(5,3,3),(5,4,3),(5,5,3)} 734/4576
{(4,3,7),(4,4,7),(4,5,7),(4,6,7),(5,3,7),(5,4,7),(5,5,7),(5,6,7)} 1020/4576
{(5,1,1),(5,2,1),(5,3,1),(5,4,1),(6,1,1),(6,2,1),(6,3,1),(6,4,1)} 1449/4576
{(5,1,2),(5,2,2),(5,3,2),(5,4,2),(6,1,2),(6,2,2),(6,3,2),(6,4,2)} 2275/4576
{(5,1,7),(5,2,7),(5,3,7),(5,4,7),(6,1,7),(6,2,7),(6,3,7),(6,4,7)} 528/4576
{(5,3,5),(5,4,5),(5,5,5),(5,6,5),(6,3,5),(6,4,5),(6,5,5),(6,6,5)} 405/4576
{(5,4,1),(5,5,1),(5,6,1),(5,7,1),(6,4,1),(6,5,1),(6,6,1),(6,7,1)} 950/4576
{(5,4,6),(5,5,6),(5,6,6),(5,7,6),(6,4,6),(6,5,6),(6,6,6),(6,7,6)} 1621/4576
{(5,4,7),(5,5,7),(5,6,7),(5,7,7),(6,4,7),(6,5,7),(6,6,7),(6,7,7)} 1110/4576
{(6,1,3),(6,2,3),(6,3,3),(6,4,3),(7,1,3),(7,2,3),(7,3,3),(7,4,3)} 1182/4576
{(6,1,7),(6,2,7),(6,3,7),(6,4,7),(7,1,7),(7,2,7),(7,3,7),(7,4,7)} 335/4576
{(6,2,1),(6,3,1),(6,4,1),(6,5,1),(7,2,1),(7,3,1),(7,4,1),(7,5,1)} 614/4576
{(6,2,3),(6,3,3),(6,4,3),(6,5,3),(7,2,3),(7,3,3),(7,4,3),(7,5,3)} 504/4576
{(6,3,7),(6,4,7),(6,5,7),(6,6,7),(7,3,7),(7,4,7),(7,5,7),(7,6,7)} 1168/4576
{(6,4,1),(6,5,1),(6,6,1),(6,7,1),(7,4,1),(7,5,1),(7,6,1),(7,7,1)} 917/4576
{(6,4,3),(6,5,3),(6,6,3),(6,7,3),(7,4,3),(7,5,3),(7,6,3),(7,7,3)} 1093/4576
{(6,4,4),(6,5,4),(6,6,4),(6,7,4),(7,4,4),(7,5,4),(7,6,4),(7,7,4)} 1402/4576
{(6,4,5),(6,5,5),(6,6,5),(6,7,5),(7,4,5),(7,5,5),(7,6,5),(7,7,5)} 997/4576
{(1,1,1),(1,1,2),(2,1,1),(2,1,2),(3,1,1),(3,1,2),(4,1,1),(4,1,2)} 885/4576
{(1,1,2),(1,1,3),(2,1,2),(2,1,3),(3,1,2),(3,1,3),(4,1,2),(4,1,3)} 1257/4576
{(1,1,5),(1,1,6),(2,1,5),(2,1,6),(3,1,5),(3,1,6),(4,1,5),(4,1,6)} 105/4576
{(1,1,6),(1,1,7),(2,1,6),(2,1,7),(3,1,6),(3,1,7),(4,1,6),(4,1,7)} 600/4576
{(1,2,2),(1,2,3),(2,2,2),(2,2,3),(3,2,2),(3,2,3),(4,2,2),(4,2,3)} 404/4576
{(1,2,5),(1,2,6),(2,2,5),(2,2,6),(3,2,5),(3,2,6),(4,2,5),(4,2,6)} 784/4576
{(1,3,1),(1,3,2),(2,3,1),(2,3,2),(3,3,1),(3,3,2),(4,3,1),(4,3,2)} 502/4576
{(1,4,1),(1,4,2),(2,4,1),(2,4,2),(3,4,1),(3,4,2),(4,4,1),(4,4,2)} 681/4576
{(1,4,3),(1,4,4),(2,4,3),(2,4,4),(3,4,3),(3,4,4),(4,4,3),(4,4,4)} 492/4576
{(1,4,4),(1,4,5),(2,4,4),(2,4,5),(3,4,4),(3,4,5),(4,4,4),(4,4,5)} 986/4576
{(1,5,1),(1,5,2),(2,5,1),(2,5,2),(3,5,1),(3,5,2),(4,5,1),(4,5,2)} 1107/4576
{(1,6,2),(1,6,3),(2,6,2),(2,6,3),(3,6,2),(3,6,3),(4,6,2),(4,6,3)} 1716/4576
{(1,7,2),(1,7,3),(2,7,2),(2,7,3),(3,7,2),(3,7,3),(4,7,2),(4,7,3)} 1119/4576
{(1,7,5),(1,7,6),(2,7,5),(2,7,6),(3,7,5),(3,7,6),(4,7,5),(4,7,6)} 511/4576
{(1,7,6),(1,7,7),(2,7,6),(2,7,7),(3,7,6),(3,7,7),(4,7,6),(4,7,7)} 597/4576
{(2,1,3),(2,1,4),(3,1,3),(3,1,4),(4,1,3),(4,1,4),(5,1,3),(5,1,4)} 230/4576
{(2,1,6),(2,1,7),(3,1,6),(3,1,7),(4,1,6),(4,1,7),(5,1,6),(5,1,7)} 415/4576
{(2,3,3),(2,3,4),(3,3,3),(3,3,4),(4,3,3),(4,3,4),(5,3,3),(5,3,4)} 745/4576
{(2,3,6),(2,3,7),(3,3,6),(3,3,7),(4,3,6),(4,3,7),(5,3,6),(5,3,7)} 298/4576
{(2,5,1),(2,5,2),(3,5,1),(3,5,2),(4,5,1),(4,5,2),(5,5,1),(5,5,2)} 679/4576
{(2,5,4),(2,5,5),(3,5,4),(3,5,5),(4,5,4),(4,5,5),(5,5,4),(5,5,5)} 1516/4576
{(2,5,6),(2,5,7),(3,5,6),(3,5,7),(4,5,6),(4,5,7),(5,5,6),(5,5,7)} 278/4576
{(2,7,1),(2,7,2),(3,7,1),(3,7,2),(4,7,1),(4,7,2),(5,7,1),(5,7,2)} 73/4576
{(3,3,3),(3,3,4),(4,3,3),(4,3,4),(5,3,3),(5,3,4),(6,3,3),(6,3,4)} 479/4576
{(3,3,6),(3,3,7),(4,3,6),(4,3,7),(5,3,6),(5,3,7),(6,3,6),(6,3,7)} 430/4576
{(3,5,1),(3,5,2),(4,5,1),(4,5,2),(5,5,1),(5,5,2),(6,5,1),(6,5,2)} 668/4576
{(3,5,4),(3,5,5),(4,5,4),(4,5,5),(5,5,4),(5,5,5),(6,5,4),(6,5,5)} 758/4576
{(3,5,6),(3,5,7),(4,5,6),(4,5,7),(5,5,6),(5,5,7),(6,5,6),(6,5,7)} 464/4576
{(3,7,6),(3,7,7),(4,7,6),(4,7,7),(5,7,6),(5,7,7),(6,7,6),(6,7,7)} 423/4576
{(4,1,2),(4,1,3),(5,1,2),(5,1,3),(6,1,2),(6,1,3),(7,1,2),(7,1,3)} 68/4576
{(4,1,5),(4,1,6),(5,1,5),(5,1,6),(6,1,5),(6,1,6),(7,1,5),(7,1,6)} 1309/4576
{(4,1,6),(4,1,7),(5,1,6),(5,1,7),(6,1,6),(6,1,7),(7,1,6),(7,1,7)} 893/4576
{(4,2,2),(4,2,3),(5,2,2),(5,2,3),(6,2,2),(6,2,3),(7,2,2),(7,2,3)} 460/4576
{(4,2,5),(4,2,6),(5,2,5),(5,2,6),(6,2,5),(6,2,6),(7,2,5),(7,2,6)} 413/4576
{(4,4,1),(4,4,2),(5,4,1),(5,4,2),(6,4,1),(6,4,2),(7,4,1),(7,4,2)} 102/4576
{(4,4,4),(4,4,5),(5,4,4),(5,4,5),(6,4,4),(6,4,5),(7,4,4),(7,4,5)} 494/4576
{(4,5,1),(4,5,2),(5,5,1),(5,5,2),(6,5,1),(6,5,2),(7,5,1),(7,5,2)} 956/4576
{(4,5,6),(4,5,7),(5,5,6),(5,5,7),(6,5,6),(6,5,7),(7,5,6),(7,5,7)} 516/4576
{(4,6,2),(4,6,3),(5,6,2),(5,6,3),(6,6,2),(6,6,3),(7,6,2),(7,6,3)} 504/4576
{(4,6,5),(4,6,6),(5,6,5),(5,6,6),(6,6,5),(6,6,6),(7,6,5),(7,6,6)} 1472/4576
{(4,7,1),(4,7,2),(5,7,1),(5,7,2),(6,7,1),(6,7,2),(7,7,1),(7,7,2)} 1093/4576
{(4,7,2),(4,7,3),(5,7,2),(5,7,3),(6,7,2),(6,7,3),(7,7,2),(7,7,3)} 680/4576
{(4,7,5),(4,7,6),(5,7,5),(5,7,6),(6,7,5),(6,7,6),(7,7,5),(7,7,6)} 686/4576
{(1,1,3),(1,2,3),(2,1,3),(2,2,3),(3,1,3),(3,2,3),(4,1,3),(4,2,3)} 368/4576
{(1,1,4),(1,2,4),(2,1,4),(2,2,4),(3,1,4),(3,2,4),(4,1,4),(4,2,4)} 731/4576
{(1,1,5),(1,2,5),(2,1,5),(2,2,5),(3,1,5),(3,2,5),(4,1,5),(4,2,5)} 1246/4576
{(1,1,7),(1,2,7),(2,1,7),(2,2,7),(3,1,7),(3,2,7),(4,1,7),(4,2,7)} 445/4576
{(1,2,1),(1,3,1),(2,2,1),(2,3,1),(3,2,1),(3,3,1),(4,2,1),(4,3,1)} 493/4576
{(1,2,2),(1,3,2),(2,2,2),(2,3,2),(3,2,2),(3,3,2),(4,2,2),(4,3,2)} 1197/4576
{(1,2,6),(1,3,6),(2,2,6),(2,3,6),(3,2,6),(3,3,6),(4,2,6),(4,3,6)} 951/4576
{(1,2,7),(1,3,7),(2,2,7),(2,3,7),(3,2,7),(3,3,7),(4,2,7),(4,3,7)} 1801/4576
{(1,4,4),(1,5,4),(2,4,4),(2,5,4),(3,4,4),(3,5,4),(4,4,4),(4,5,4)} 340/4576
{(1,5,1),(1,6,1),(2,5,1),(2,6,1),(3,5,1),(3,6,1),(4,5,1),(4,6,1)} 695/4576
{(1,5,2),(1,6,2),(2,5,2),(2,6,2),(3,5,2),(3,6,2),(4,5,2),(4,6,2)} 45/4576
{(1,5,6),(1,6,6),(2,5,6),(2,6,6),(3,5,6),(3,6,6),(4,5,6),(4,6,6)} 511/4576
{(1,6,1),(1,7,1),(2,6,1),(2,7,1),(3,6,1),(3,7,1),(4,6,1),(4,7,1)} 1786/4576
{(1,6,3),(1,7,3),(2,6,3),(2,7,3),(3,6,3),(3,7,3),(4,6,3),(4,7,3)} 685/4576
{(1,6,4),(1,7,4),(2,6,4),(2,7,4),(3,6,4),(3,7,4),(4,6,4),(4,7,4)} 1438/4576
{(1,6,5),(1,7,5),(2,6,5),(2,7,5),(3,6,5),(3,7,5),(4,6,5),(4,7,5)} 1590/4576
{(2,1,1),(2,2,1),(3,1,1),(3,2,1),(4,1,1),(4,2,1),(5,1,1),(5,2,1)} 336/4576
{(2,1,3),(2,2,3),(3,1,3),(3,2,3),(4,1,3),(4,2,3),(5,1,3),(5,2,3)} 721/4576
{(2,1,5),(2,2,5),(3,1,5),(3,2,5),(4,1,5),(4,2,5),(5,1,5),(5,2,5)} 184/4576
{(2,2,5),(2,3,5),(3,2,5),(3,3,5),(4,2,5),(4,3,5),(5,2,5),(5,3,5)} 392/4576
{(2,3,5),(2,4,5),(3,3,5),(3,4,5),(4,3,5),(4,4,5),(5,3,5),(5,4,5)} 772/4576
{(2,4,3),(2,5,3),(3,4,3),(3,5,3),(4,4,3),(4,5,3),(5,4,3),(5,5,3)} 1326/4576
{(2,5,3),(2,6,3),(3,5,3),(3,6,3),(4,5,3),(4,6,3),(5,5,3),(5,6,3)} 492/4576
{(2,6,3),(2,7,3),(3,6,3),(3,7,3),(4,6,3),(4,7,3),(5,6,3),(5,7,3)} 61/4576
{(2,6,7),(2,7,7),(3,6,7),(3,7,7),(4,6,7),(4,7,7),(5,6,7),(5,7,7)} 192/4576
{(3,1,1),(3,2,1),(4,1,1),(4,2,1),(5,1,1),(5,2,1),(6,1,1),(6,2,1)} 756/4576
{(3,1,7),(3,2,7),(4,1,7),(4,2,7),(5,1,7),(5,2,7),(6,1,7),(6,2,7)} 266/4576
{(3,3,1),(3,4,1),(4,3,1),(4,4,1),(5,3,1),(5,4,1),(6,3,1),(6,4,1)} 544/4576
{(3,3,5),(3,4,5),(4,3,5),(4,4,5),(5,3,5),(5,4,5),(6,3,5),(6,4,5)} 516/4576
{(3,4,7),(3,5,7),(4,4,7),(4,5,7),(5,4,7),(5,5,7),(6,4,7),(6,5,7)} 406/4576
{(3,6,1),(3,7,1),(4,6,1),(4,7,1),(5,6,1),(5,7,1),(6,6,1),(6,7,1)} 164/4576
{(4,1,1),(4,2,1),(5,1,1),(5,2,1),(6,1,1),(6,2,1),(7,1,1),(7,2,1)} 460/4576
{(4,1,3),(4,2,3),(5,1,3),(5,2,3),(6,1,3),(6,2,3),(7,1,3),(7,2,3)} 1093/4576
{(4,1,4),(4,2,4),(5,1,4),(5,2,4),(6,1,4),(6,2,4),(7,1,4),(7,2,4)} 1426/4576
{(4,1,5),(4,2,5),(5,1,5),(5,2,5),(6,1,5),(6,2,5),(7,1,5),(7,2,5)} 893/4576
{(4,1,7),(4,2,7),(5,1,7),(5,2,7),(6,1,7),(6,2,7),(7,1,7),(7,2,7)} 1315/4576
{(4,2,1),(4,3,1),(5,2,1),(5,3,1),(6,2,1),(6,3,1),(7,2,1),(7,3,1)} 392/4576
{(4,2,6),(4,3,6),(5,2,6),(5,3,6),(6,2,6),(6,3,6),(7,2,6),(7,3,6)} 893/4576
{(4,2,7),(4,3,7),(5,2,7),(5,3,7),(6,2,7),(6,3,7),(7,2,7),(7,3,7)} 107/4576
{(4,5,1),(4,6,1),(5,5,1),(5,6,1),(6,5,1),(6,6,1),(7,5,1),(7,6,1)} 471/4576
{(4,5,2),(4,6,2),(5,5,2),(5,6,2),(6,5,2),(6,6,2),(7,5,2),(7,6,2)} 929/4576
{(4,5,6),(4,6,6),(5,5,6),(5,6,6),(6,5,6),(6,6,6),(7,5,6),(7,6,6)} 107/4576
{(4,6,1),(4,7,1),(5,6,1),(5,7,1),(6,6,1),(6,7,1),(7,6,1),(7,7,1)} 570/4576
{(4,6,5),(4,7,5),(5,6,5),(5,7,5),(6,6,5),(6,7,5),(7,6,5),(7,7,5)} 601/4576
```

The following dual variables provide a "coloring" that certifies optimality:

```
i j k dual 
1 1 2 3/11 
1 1 4 1/11 
1 1 6 3/11 
1 2 1 4/11 
1 2 2 1/11 
1 2 4 2/11 
1 2 5 4/11 
1 2 6 1/11 
1 3 4 4/11 
1 4 2 3/11 
1 4 3 4/11 
1 4 6 3/11 
1 4 7 4/11 
1 5 2 3/11 
1 5 4 1/11 
1 5 6 3/11 
1 6 1 4/11 
1 6 2 1/11 
1 6 4 2/11 
1 6 5 4/11 
1 6 6 1/11 
1 7 4 4/11 
2 1 1 4/11 
2 1 3 1/11 
2 1 4 2/11 
2 1 5 4/11 
2 1 7 1/11 
2 2 3 4/11 
2 2 7 4/11 
2 3 2 4/11 
2 3 3 1/11 
2 3 4 2/11 
2 3 6 4/11 
2 3 7 1/11 
2 4 1 3/11 
2 4 3 1/11 
2 4 5 3/11 
2 4 7 1/11 
2 5 1 4/11 
2 5 3 1/11 
2 5 4 2/11 
2 5 5 4/11 
2 5 7 1/11 
2 6 3 4/11 
2 6 7 4/11 
2 7 2 4/11 
2 7 3 1/11 
2 7 4 2/11 
2 7 6 4/11 
2 7 7 1/11 
3 1 4 4/11 
3 2 2 3/11 
3 2 3 2/11 
3 2 4 2/11 
3 2 6 3/11 
3 2 7 2/11 
3 3 2 3/11 
3 3 4 1/11 
3 3 6 3/11 
3 4 1 4/11 
3 4 2 1/11 
3 4 3 2/11 
3 4 5 4/11 
3 4 6 1/11 
3 4 7 2/11 
3 5 4 4/11 
3 6 2 3/11 
3 6 3 2/11 
3 6 4 2/11 
3 6 6 3/11 
3 6 7 2/11 
3 7 2 3/11 
3 7 4 1/11 
3 7 6 3/11 
4 1 2 4/11 
4 1 3 3/11 
4 1 6 4/11 
4 1 7 3/11 
4 2 1 3/11 
4 2 3 1/11 
4 2 5 3/11 
4 2 7 1/11 
4 3 1 4/11 
4 3 3 3/11 
4 3 5 4/11 
4 3 7 3/11 
4 4 4 4/11 
4 5 2 4/11 
4 5 3 3/11 
4 5 6 4/11 
4 5 7 3/11 
4 6 1 3/11 
4 6 3 1/11 
4 6 5 3/11 
4 6 7 1/11 
4 7 1 4/11 
4 7 3 3/11 
4 7 5 4/11 
4 7 7 3/11 
5 1 2 3/11 
5 1 4 1/11 
5 1 6 3/11 
5 2 1 4/11 
5 2 2 1/11 
5 2 4 2/11 
5 2 5 4/11 
5 2 6 1/11 
5 3 4 4/11 
5 4 2 3/11 
5 4 3 4/11 
5 4 6 3/11 
5 4 7 4/11 
5 5 2 3/11 
5 5 4 1/11 
5 5 6 3/11 
5 6 1 4/11 
5 6 2 1/11 
5 6 4 2/11 
5 6 5 4/11 
5 6 6 1/11 
5 7 4 4/11 
6 1 1 4/11 
6 1 3 1/11 
6 1 4 2/11 
6 1 5 4/11 
6 1 7 1/11 
6 2 3 4/11 
6 2 7 4/11 
6 3 2 4/11 
6 3 3 1/11 
6 3 4 2/11 
6 3 6 4/11 
6 3 7 1/11 
6 4 1 3/11 
6 4 3 1/11 
6 4 5 3/11 
6 4 7 1/11 
6 5 1 4/11 
6 5 3 1/11 
6 5 4 2/11 
6 5 5 4/11 
6 5 7 1/11 
6 6 3 4/11 
6 6 7 4/11 
6 7 2 4/11 
6 7 3 1/11 
6 7 4 2/11 
6 7 6 4/11 
6 7 7 1/11 
7 1 4 4/11 
7 2 2 3/11 
7 2 3 2/11 
7 2 4 2/11 
7 2 6 3/11 
7 2 7 2/11 
7 3 2 3/11 
7 3 4 1/11 
7 3 6 3/11 
7 4 1 4/11 
7 4 2 1/11 
7 4 3 2/11 
7 4 5 4/11 
7 4 6 1/11 
7 4 7 2/11 
7 5 4 4/11 
7 6 2 3/11 
7 6 3 2/11 
7 6 4 2/11 
7 6 6 3/11 
7 6 7 2/11 
7 7 2 3/11 
7 7 4 1/11 
7 7 6 3/11
```

For this coloring, every $1\times2\times4$ box has sum of colors equal to $1$, and the sum of colors in the big cube is $41+9/11$, so you cannot pack more than $41+9/11$ disjoint boxes.

Comment: What do you mean by "maximum objective value"?

Comment: The largest possible value of $\sum_b x_b$ subject to the constraints.

Comment: How exactly does the dual make a coloring?

Comment: Multiply both sides of each constraint by the dual values and add them up.  The resulting inequality turns out to be $\sum_b x_b \le 41+9/11$.

Comment: Does this mean that each possible 1x2x4 cuboid adds up to at least 1 under the dual "coloring"?

Comment: Is there a cuboid that adds up to more than 1?

Comment: @mathlander Imagine you could put things like $\frac3{11}$ of a cuboid in the cube. If, despite this _LP relaxation_, you still can't pack (part-)cuboids summing to 42 whole cuboids, impossibility is already proven as the whole-cuboid packings are a strict subset of the part-cuboid packings.

Comment: And then normal, real-valued linear programs like this are fairly easy to solve. To each such program is a dual, and optimal solutions to the dual correspond to optimal solutions in the primal, with the same objective value for each.

Comment: The dual values for the cells in each cuboid add up to exactly $1$.

Comment: @RobPratt Is it possible to do better than $41\frac{9}{11}$?

Comment: @mathlander No.

Comment: No, that is the maximum, and the dual variables prove the upper bound.  By the way, this approach is the same as in this answer you linked to a couple weeks ago: https://puzzling.stackexchange.com/a/90333/65277

Comment: @RobPratt How exactly do the dual variables prove the upper bound? There is a way to color 42 cells such that each 1x2x4 box contains exactly one colored cell. There is even a way to color 46. Similarly, there might be a way to color less than $41\frac{9}{11}$.

Comment: With the "coloring" above with "colors" $1/11,2/11,3/11,4/11$, every box has sum of colors equal to $1$, and the sum of colors in the big cube is $41+9/11$, so you cannot have more than $41+9/11$ disjoint boxes.

Comment: Oops, I didn't clarify what I mean by "better". Is it possible to have a better upper bound than $41\frac{9}{11}$?

Comment: No, this is the best such LP upper bound because there is a fractional solution $x_b\in[0,1]$ with $\sum_b x_b = 41+9/11$, but that implies for integer $x_b$ an upper bound of $\lfloor 41+9/11\rfloor = 41$.  By the way, you can think of the "volume" argument that yields upper bound $7^3/8$ as coloring every cell with dual value $1/8$.

Comment: What fractions are the numbers for the fractional solution based on?

Comment: The denominators seem to be divisors of 4576.

Comment: The solver uses floating-point arithmetic, so there typically won't be an exact rational representation with small denominators.